# Compare dates using Dateserial in Access 2007 SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT P1.Column1, P1.NextApprovalDate
FROM Procedures P1
WHERE DATESERIAL(YEAR(P1.NextApprovalDate), MONTH(P1.NextApprovalDate), 1 )  
= DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date()), MONTH(DATE()) + 1, 1);
```

I get an error which is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". I tried using the CDate and the Format functions in conjunction as well but continue to get the same error. The SQL runs fine when I am selecting the criteria there. How should the criteria be formatted?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `Procedures.NextApprovalDate` field?  Does the table allow Null in that field?

Comment: @HansUp It is a Date/Time field and yes it does allow nulls

Comment: `Year(Null)` returns Null.  `Month(Null)` also returns Null.  That means your first `DateSerial` condition would be equivalent to this: `DateSerial(null, null, 1)` ... and that is not acceptable.  Change the table design to prohibit Null in `NextApprovalDate` or refactor to query so that it never submits Null values to `DateSerial`.

Comment: @HansUp  Thanks. The moment you asked the null question, I kind of knew where this was going. I have to allow nulls unfortunately. How do I change the query so that is never submits null values? can the iif be used in the query?

Comment: I think you must first decide whether you want rows with Null `NextApprovalDate` to be included in the query's result set.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp. No, I did not want to include those rows. I added the NOT ISNULL condition however still get the error. The NOT ISNULL(P1.NextApprovalDate) by itself worked fine and returned the rows that only had valid values

Comment: I'm running out of time.  Try an approach like this: `SELECT P1.Column1, P1.NextApprovalDate FROM ( SELECT Column1, NextApprovalDate FROM Procedures WHERE NextApprovalDate Is Not Null) AS P1 WHERE DATESERIAL(YEAR(P1.NextApprovalDate), MONTH(P1.NextApprovalDate), 1 )  
= DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date()), MONTH(DATE()) + 1, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I got this to work but it is kind of weird the way Access wanted it. The = sign never worked for the comparison. Why I don't know. The BETWEEN worked. If someone could find a way to make the '=' work, do let me know. Thanks to @Hansup for pointing me in the right direction.

```
SELECT P2.Column1, P2.NextApprovalDate
FROM (SELECT Procedures.Column1, Procedures.NextApprovalDate FROM   
Procedures WHERE Procedures.NextApprovalDate IS NOT NULL)  AS P2
WHERE DATESERIAL(YEAR(P2.NextApprovalDate),MONTH(P2.NextApprovalDate),1)   
Between DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date()),MONTH(Date())+1,1) And  
DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date()),MONTH(Date())+1,1);
```